# Regex running on wordpress tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm calling wordpress API and getting the content of a post, but it has tags in there and I'm trying to filter them out to get the actual HTML, here's a sample:

```
   <p>[vc_row css=&#8221;.vc_custom_1499904320526{margin-top: 0px 
   !important;border-top-width: 0px !important;padding-top: 5px 
   !important;}&#8221;][vc_column][vc_custom_heading 
   source=&#8221;post_title&#8221; 
   font_container=&#8221;tag:h2|text_align:center&#8221; 
   use_theme_fonts=&#8221;yes&#8221;][vc_column_text]<strong>START 
   HERE</strong></p>\n<p>Release Date:<br />\nVersion:</p>\n<p>I am text 
   block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper 
   mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>\n<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column]
   [/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width=&#8221;1/4&#8243; 
   offset=&#8221;vc_hidden-lg vc_hidden-md vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs&#8221;]
   <style type=\"text/css\" scoped=\"scoped\">
```

I tried using Regex to get rid of anything between those square brackets `[` `]`
and here's what I wrote: `/\[[^]]*\]/g`.
This pattern matches when I run it on a [regex website](https://regex101.com/), however when I do this:

```
var exp = /\[[^]]*\]/g;
console.info('WP resp',latestReleaseNotes.content.rendered.search(exp));
```

It consoles out a -1 and doesn't match:

`WP resp -1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regex to parse html tags?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what should I be using? The end result I'm aiming for is just HTML without wordpress tags

Comment: Use correct language setting in regex101. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCIvjy/1) vs. [correct regex](https://regex101.com/r/iCIvjy/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `]` inside the other `[]` because it otherwise closes the expression.

```
var exp = /\[[^\]]*\]/g
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/kuneyixowi/edit?console)